# How to interpret a union type as one of the component types

Tags: typescript, types, casting, phaser-framework

For a little educational side-project I'm working on, I'm using the Phaser CE framework in a factory class, such that `Phaser.Text` elements that are generated by it are automatically styled consistently, based on a JSON file that I write with the predefined styles.

However, I also have an `INamed` property that I stick on things that have names.  This also has extensions on `Array<>` that let me get an item from an array by name easily.

Thus, in theory I can take data like this:

**styles.json:**

```
{
    "text": [
        {
            "name": "default",
            "fill": "#FFF",
            "stroke": "#333",
            "strokeWidth": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "snazzy",
            "fill": "#F33",
            "stroke": "#633",
            "strokeWidth": 2
        },
    ]
}
```

...and using our text factory...

**TextFactory.ts:**

```
namespace Main.UI {
    export class TextFactory {
        public styles: (Phaser.PhaserTextStyle & INamed)[] = [];

         public constructor() {}

         public initialize() {
             const data = game.cache.getJSON('ui-styles');
             const textStyles = data['text'];

             for (let current of textStyles) {
                 this.styles.push(current);
             }
        }

        public create(
            x: number,
            y: number,
            text: string,
            style?: string
        ): Phaser.Text {
            let styleData: (Phaser.PhaserTextStyle & INamed);
            if (!style)
                styleData = this.styles[0];
            else
                styleData = this.styles.getByName(style);

            // !!! Problem is here !!!
            const newText = game.add.text(x, y, text, <Phaser.PhaserTextStyle>styleData);
            return newText;
        }
    }
}
```

...and use it in a game state:

**GameState.ts:**

```
namespace Main.States {
    export class GameState extends Phaser.State {
        private textFactory: UI.TextFactory = null;

        public preload(): void {
            game.load.json('ui-styles', 'assets/data/styles.json');
        }

        public create(): void {
            this.textFactory = new UI.TextFactory();
            this.textFactory.initialize();

            const testText = this.textFactory.create(2, 2, "This should be white with a dark gray outline...");
            const otherText = this.textFactory.create(2, 52, "SNAZZY!", "snazzy");
        }
    }
}
```

If you run that general setup with the relevant boilerplate in Phaser, the text will render, but will be black and unstyled.  I've performed some sanity checks, and found that the union type `(Phaser.PhaserTextStyle & INamed)` is what seems to be causing me trouble - the call to `game.add.text` is only expecting a `Phaser.PhaserTextStyle`.

I tried casting the `textStyle` variable in `TextFactory.create` to just being a `Phaser.PhaserTextStyle`, but that didn't seem effective - my text still renders unstyled.  I did some further 'Silly Developer' checks, like making sure I'd saved and built my changes, and adding debug messages, but those didn't yield any insights to help see what new silly thing I've clearly done.  Thus, my question...

***Question:*** In what way can I take an object of a type like `(A & B)` in TypeScript and just use it as either the `A` or `B` types?

Comment: I don't think the type of the object has any bearing on the issue. At most the `game.add.text` is getting tripped up by the extra property.  Type assertions don't do anything at runtime. You can remove the extra property with `delete styleData['name']` or you can create a new object without it using a spread `let { name, ...styleDataNoName } = styleData;`

Comment: Titian - your comment helped me find the true answer.  It's close enough, though - mind making your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I made it an answer, 10x :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the type of the object has any bearing on the issue.

The `game.add.text` function might have a problem with the extra `name` property on the object.

Type assertions don't do anything at runtime, so you can use them to remove a property, you can use them just to change the type the compiler knows (which in this case does not help).

You can remove the extra property with delete :

```
delete styleData['name']
```

or you can create a new object without the property and use that, using a spread :

```
let { name, ...styleDataNoName } = styleData;
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: the only type-safe way to use `A & B` as either `A` or `B` is by using type guards. However, even this approach has limitations.

Consider the following edge case in which both shapes have a field of the same name (`id`):

```
interface A {
    name: string;
    id: string;
}

interface B {
    id: number;
}

type Intersection = A & B;

const test: Intersection = {
    id: 0, // Error — cannot be implemented! Nothing is both a string and a number
    name: ''
}
```

Intersecting `A` and `B` tells TypeScript that the `id` property needs to be both `string & number` at the same time, which cannot be accomplished. Even though such a concept exists on the type level, it cannot have a runtime representation.

Even if — hypothetically — we could have an `Intersection` (someone could use a type assertion), TypeScript will allow us to write code that will explode in runtime.

```
declare function alpha(argument: A): void;
declare function beta(argument: B): void;

declare const intersection: Intersection;

alpha(intersection); // TypeScript allows that, but it can fail in runtime if `alpha` expects `id` to be of type `string`.
```

One can mitigate the risk by creating user-defined type guards.

```
/**
 * Type-safe approach.
 */
declare function isA(argument: unknown): argument is A;
declare function isB(argument: unknown): argument is B;

if (isA(intersection)) {
    alpha(intersection);
}

if (isB(intersection)) {
    beta(intersection);
}
```

Unfortunately, these need to exist in runtime, and there is nothing that stops the developer from implementing them incorrectly.

Comment: I didn't realize that `A & B` had those kinds of issues associated with them.  I'll try to avoid using intersections like these unless I absolutely have to.